# Show a custom field from the checkout of woocommerce on the quick view of the order page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I foollow all he steps from this tutorial: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

```
    // Hook in
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

    // Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
    function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
         $fields['shipping']['shipping_phone'] = array(
         'label'     => __('Phone', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('Phone', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => false,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true
         );

         return $fields;
    }

    /**
     * Display field value on the order edit page
     */

    add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

    function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Phone From Checkout Form').':</strong> ' .        get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_shipping_phone', true ) . '</p>';
    }
```

And everything works fine, but... I want to show the value of the new field on the quickview from the order page, all the tutorials I find, only show how to show them on the detail page of the orders.

Thanks!

Comment: It is good practice to show the code you have completed in order for SO to more effectively help.

Comment: thanks! I edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an action to show custom fields in the order preview box:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_preview_start', 'custom_display_order_data_in_admin' );
```

or:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_preview_end', 'custom_display_order_data_in_admin' );
```

But as you might noticed, these two actions will add custom fields either at the beginning or the end of it.

EDIT:
The whole code I've used in my custom plugin is this:

```
function custom_display_order_data_in_admin( $order ){  ?>
        <div class="order_data_column">
            <div class="address">
            <?php
                echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'billing cart' ) . ':</strong>' . get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_cart', true ) . '</p>';
             ?>
            </div>
            <div class="edit_address">
                <?php woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 'id' => '_billing_cart', 'label' => __( 'billing cart' ), 'wrapper_class' => '_billing_company_field' ) ); ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    <?php }

    add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'custom_display_order_data_in_admin' );

    add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_preview_end', 'custom_display_order_data_in_admin' );
```

**You should just change the parameters as you used in you own code**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I try to use the code, but it didn't work for me. Can you please make an snippet? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to work with "snippet" things :D

I will edit my answer to add the whole code I've used in my custom plugin

Comment: How did you get order ID in the preview to work, please? I tried to use similar snippet, but $order is empty in preview, works only for the first action

Comment: I'm also facing the issue of getting order id in the function.